# Laravel: saving images in app public folder

Tags: php, image, laravel, security

How do you think I should organize images storage in my Laravel app? For example, I have a self-build admin panel and Articles module. Every article can have image that I should upload from Article's edit page in admin panel. So this image should be accessible through, for example, /images/somehash.jpg. But I can't give app privileges to write in public folder for security reasons. What variants of resolving this problem I have?

1. Create private folder e.g. {app_root}/storage/images, create route that handles URL /images/*, read image from storage and return it;
2. Maybe some workarounds with .htaccess;
3. You variant(s)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not write to the public folder, what exact security reasons do you have?

Comment: I mean if I will make writable public folder in UNIX system - everybody can write there (if use PHP as Apache module) and this will be potencial security hole

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the images in `public` directory, then create `storage/app/images` directory and store the images in it.

Depending on your application's requirements, you may or may not need to create routes to read these images.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you save your images in your public folder or a private folder, depends on your logic. When you upload your files in a public folder then those files can be downloaded directly from the web server without starting the 
Laravel application. But if you choose to store your files in a private folder then those files are private and the requester has to get those files from your Laravel application. So if your files are open to everybody(like CSS or JS files) then that means you can put them in a public folder. But if for any reason your files have any kind of restriction or any validation that needs to be checked before letting the users to access that file, then you can upload those files in a private folder.